# Issue with ASINetworkQueue?

Tags: ios, xcode, asihttprequest, asinetworkqueue

I am using ASINetworkQueue to upload files.I am adding two ASIFormDataRequest in the ASINetworkQueue.I have added this code while creating Queue

```
 [networkQueue setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadFilesCompleted:)];
```

I am facing two issues

**1.Completion block is calling two times.ie for each completion of ASIFormDataRequest,it gets calling.I want it to call only once,i.e. after the completion of 2 requests

2.In the completion am getting

```
- (void)uploadFilesCompleted:(ASINetworkQueue *)networkQ
{
    NSLog(@"uploadFilesCompleted '%@'",networkQ);

}

***2014-01-20 10:17:52.813 MyProject[39671:a0b] uploadFilesCompleted '<ASIFormDataRequest: 0xcba5400>'

2014-01-20 10:17:53.672 MyProject[39671:a0b] uploadFilesCompleted '<ASIFormDataRequest: 0xcba4000>'***
```

instead of ASINetworkQueue**

Any help will be appreciable ?

Comment: The ASI suite of networking convenience classes stopped active develop ment in September 2011 (http://allseeing-i.com/[request_release];). Which is an age in iOS terms. You're far better off moving to something more modern such as AFNetworking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
[networkQueue setQueueDidFinishSelector:@selector(queueDidFinish:)];
```

That selector is only called when the whole queue has finished:

```
- (void)queueDidFinish:(ASINetworkQueue *)queue {
    NSLog(@"uploadFilesCompleted '%@'",networkQ);
}
```

The selectors that you use are called everytime a single request from the queue has finished and the parameter that is handed to those selector is the request object and not the queue object.